# Uniroot: End points not of opposite signs (while they have) for QF

Tags: r, statistics, quantile

I am trying to program manually a quantile function, to do so and to ilustrate my point I propose the next CDF (which is in fact the same one as  *pnorm(x,mean=1, sd=0)* ):

```
cdf = function(x){
  integrate(function(x) {dnorm(x, mean=1)},lower = -Inf, upper=x)$value 
}
```

Then I use the root function in the code of the quantile function, and test it generating the next error message:

```
qf = function(q){
  uniroot(function(x)
    {cdf(x)-q},
    interval=c(-Inf, Inf))$root
}

qf(0.5)
-----------------------------------------------
Error in uniroot(function(x) { : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

At first I thought it was due to the infinite interval, so I changed it to big values with opposite sign such as: c(-1000, 1000).

What can I do to fix it or alternatively *program* my quantile function by using a different way?

Comment: The error is not about the `interval` values. It is about the y values of the anonymous function at these x values.

Comment: I see. Then maybe there is no way to uniroot the CDF of a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the bad behavior of `integrate` with `lower = -Inf, upper = -Inf` as Roland pointed out, it also poorly samples the space to be integrated before giving up when the endpoints are very close to 0:

```
pdf <- function(x, mean = 0, sd = 1) {
  p <- dnorm(x, mean, sd)
  print(c(x = x, pdf = p))
  return(p)
}

cdf <- function(x){
  integrate(pdf, lower = -Inf, upper=x)
}

cdf(-1000)
#>        x1        x2        x3        x4        x5        x6        x7        x8 
#> -1001.000 -1233.065 -1000.004 -1038.299 -1000.026 -1013.800 -1000.072 -1006.738 
#>        x9       x10       x11       x12       x13       x14       x15      pdf1 
#> -1000.148 -1003.832 -1000.261 -1002.366 -1000.423 -1001.525 -1000.656     0.000 
#>      pdf2      pdf3      pdf4      pdf5      pdf6      pdf7      pdf8      pdf9 
#>     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000 
#>     pdf10     pdf11     pdf12     pdf13     pdf14     pdf15 
#>     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000
#> 0 with absolute error < 0
cdf(1000)
#>       x1       x2       x3       x4       x5       x6       x7       x8 
#> 999.0000 766.9348 999.9957 961.7012 999.9739 986.2000 999.9275 993.2621 
#>       x9      x10      x11      x12      x13      x14      x15     pdf1 
#> 999.8516 996.1681 999.7390 997.6339 999.5774 998.4754 999.3441   0.0000 
#>     pdf2     pdf3     pdf4     pdf5     pdf6     pdf7     pdf8     pdf9 
#>   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000 
#>    pdf10    pdf11    pdf12    pdf13    pdf14    pdf15 
#>   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
#> 0 with absolute error < 0
```

One workaround is to split the integral at a value whose density is further from 0, then set a wide *finite* search interval around the mean in `uniroot`:

```
cdf <- function(x, mean = 0, sd = 1) {
  if (x > mean) {
    integrate(function(x) dnorm(x, mean, sd), lower = -Inf, upper = mean)$value +
      integrate(function(x) dnorm(x, mean, sd), lower = mean, upper = x)$value
  } else {
    integrate(function(x) dnorm(x, mean, sd), lower = -Inf, upper = x)$value
  }
}

qf <- function(q, mean = 0, sd = 1) {
  uniroot(function(x) cdf(x, mean, sd) - q, interval = c(-sd, sd)*100 + mean)$root
}

qf(0.5, 1)
#> [1] 1
qnorm(0.5, 1)
#> [1] 1
qf(0.6, 1)
#> [1] 1.253346
qnorm(0.6, 1)
#> [1] 1.253347
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote the documentation of `integrate`:

> Like all numerical integration routines, these evaluate the function
> on a finite set of points. If the function is approximately constant
> (in particular, zero) over nearly all its range it is possible that
> the result and error estimate may be seriously wrong.

That is the core of your issue. Check out this:

```
integrate(function(x) {dnorm(x, mean=1)},lower = -Inf, upper = -Inf)
#1 with absolute error < 1.6e-05
```

That's obviously wrong. The error from `uniroot` is a result of this. You should not integrate a density function numerically if you can avoid it.